# Fixed voltage source & maximized power

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, power, electrical-engineering

The goal of a voltage source like a battery for example is that it will provide a fixed voltage regardless of the load resistance. The battery has internal resistance Ri

If  R_L≫R_i, the voltage source is a good fixed source. However in order to have the maximized power dissipate in the R_L  , that will happens when R_L=R_i.

So how do we archiving both features? To have a good voltage source that would provide a fixed voltage regardless of the load resistance and to have the maximized power?

Is there a formula or an industrial method to have both?

Comment: *"To have a good voltage source **that would provide a fixed voltage regardless of the load resistance** and to have the maximized power"* - the simple answer is that for the bolded constraint to hold, it must be that the internal resistance is *zero* (or effectively so for the minimum specified load resistance).

Answer (score 0):

First, a source that fixes the voltage across its terminals regardless of load resistance has, by definition, zero internal resistance:

$$V_S = V_{OC} \frac{R_L}{r_i + R_L}$$

where $V_{OC}$ is the *open-circuit* $(R_L = \infty)$ terminal voltage.

See that, for finite $R_L \gt 0$, we have $V_S = V_{OC}$ only if $r_i = 0$.

Now, the power delivered to a load is given by

$$P_L = \frac{V_s^2}{R_L} = V_{OC}^2\frac{R_L}{(r_i + R_L)^2}$$

See that, for $r_i = 0$, the power delivered is more than for any $r_i > 0$ and so, in this sense, is maximum.

However, if one were to ask what is the maximum power the source can deliver, the answer is that, for $r_i = 0$, the power delivered can be arbitrarily large which is clearly unphysical.  Thus, while we can make $r_i$ small, we cannot physically make it zero.